# Backbone View not appending on Collection change

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I have a text input which I use to collect a keyword from the user, and then send an ajax request (which is getting successful results). I would like to append the `<ul>` with `<li>` items, each representing a result.

Here is the  which includes the search input and should get the appended `<li>` results.

```
<div class="search_group pull-right">   
    <h5><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="show-groups">Find Other Groups<span class="caret"></span></a></h5>
    <ul>
        <li class="search-input">
            <input type="text" class="search" name="search">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have the following underscore template which would ideally represent each result in the collection.

```
<script type="text/template" class="template" id="template-search-result">
    <% _.each(results,function(result){ %>
        <li class="result">
            <a href="/surnames/<%=URL%>">
                <%=result.name%>
                <span><%=result.members%> &ndash; Members</span>
                <span><%=result.ancestors%> &ndash; Ancestors</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    <% }); %>
</script>
```

And now, my Backbone code.

I fetch my Results collection after the user enters something in the input field, and when that collection returns results from my server (which I can see successfully in the console), I would expect the ResultView to append the ul with additional li results.

```
window.Results = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    url: function() {
        return '/ajax/groups/search?q=' + query;
    }

});

var results = new Results();

window.SearchInput = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: ".search-input input",
    events: {
        "change": "getResults",
        "keyup": "getResults",
        "keydown": "getResults",
        "paste": "getResults"
    },
    getResults: function() {
        query = $('input').val();
        results.fetch();
    }
});

var searchInput = new SearchInput({ collection: results });

window.ResultView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: ".search-group ul",
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.collection.bind('change', this.render);
        this.template = _.template($("#template-search-result").html());
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.append( this.template( {results: this.collection.toJSON()} ));
        return this;
    }
});

var resultView = new ResultView({ collection: results });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining the "el" in my ResultView as:

```
el: ".search-group ul",
```

I changed it to an id and modified my markup accordingly:

```
el: "#result-list",
```

and:

```
<ul id="result-list">
    <li class="search-input">
        <input type="text" class="search" name="search">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're either looking for the `add` or `reset` events, depending how you're loading your collection.

If you're doing a `fetch`, you'll want to listen to `reset`. If you are adding models to the collection manually, or calling `fetch({update:true})`, you'll get the  `add` events.

The collection `change` event only fires when the one of the collection's models fires a `change` of its own.

Here's a [list of all the built-in Backbone events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog) for reference.